# How can we get page load time in load testing in visual studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, performance-testing, load-testing, page-load-time

When we perform load testing with concurrent users (like 5, 10 25 etc) in visual studio 2015, we will get the average response time.

**Is there any way to get page load time for an individual user in web load testing?**

If yes, what is the procedure to get this?

OR

**Is there any other tool by which we can get the Page Load Time in load testing for the multiple users?**

Although we can get the page load time in our web performance test in which we run our recorded scenarios.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the "Test details" table in the Visual Studio results sufficient? All the test results at stored in an SQL database, perhaps you can do your own querying of it. But, your question is vague, please [edit] it to  more clearly specify what information you want. Please also read the [help] pages on how to write a good and on-topic question for his site.

Comment: My question is: In load testing in visual studio against the number of concurrent users, we can get the average response time instead of page load time. Is there any way in visual studio to get page load time. Or is there any other tool instead of visual studio which has feature to give Page Load Time?

Comment: Your comment just repeats your question. Please [edit] the question to provide the missing details. Have you read the [help] pages?

Comment: Hi. Why would you want to obtain the page load times for multiple users involved in the load test? If the server is slow, then all the users are going to face similar prolonged load times and if the server is normal, the load times are going to be in and around the same numbers across all users. There will never be a scenario where 1 user is having an excellent load time while another faces a huge lag under same testing conditions.